# Onto Algebra homomorphism between group rings.

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups, modules, group-rings, free-modules

I have to determine onto  $F$-Algebra  map from group algebra $FS_5$ to $M_4(F)$ where $F$ is any finite field of characteristic $2$ and $S_5$ is symmetric group of degree $5$ generated by $a=(1,2,3,4,5)~, b=(1,2)$. I tried it as follows .

I define group homomorphism between $S_5$ and $GL_4(F) $as

$
     a\rightarrow \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       0& 0& 0& 1\\
       1& 0& 0& 1\\
0& 1&0&1&\\
0&0&1&1&\\
      \end{array} } \right]
    $ and

$b\rightarrow \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       0& 0& 0& 1\\
       0& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 1&0&0&\\
1&0&0&0&\\
      \end{array} } \right]$

Now this group homomorphism can be extended to Algebra homomorphism between $FS_5$ and $M_4(F)$. But I don’t know that this is onto map or not . Please suggest me that it is onto or not. One can suggest different map that make onto Algebra homomorphism. Thanks.